# What is the equivalent to AWS PassRole permission in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, amazon-iam

In AWS, you can allow a user to pass a role to a service using the `PassRole` permissions, as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html).

How can one achieve a similar result in Azure IAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the equivalent would be `Microsoft.Authorization/write`. There is no built-in role with such a permissions, accept for `Owner`. You can create a custom role with that particular permission, but anybody having that role can give anybody any permissions, so its effectively a proxy for `Owner`.

Comment: I am reading the documentation on AWS and if I am not mistaken it is conceptually similar to Service Principal in Azure. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yes, but to grant permissions to service principal you need to have `Microsoft.Authorization/write` permissions on the subscription

Comment: as mentioned by @GauravMantri, I can see Service Principal as closely matched functionality 
Service principal - A security identity used by applications or services to access specific Azure resources. You can think of it as a user identity (username and password or certificate) for an application.

Comment: So to recap: the service will have a service principal which is its identity. That is of course to have any sort of role. Then having the ability to give permissions is `Microsoft.Authorization/write`, which can be assigned to a custom role. Given that that is no more restrictive than the `Owner`, it is probably easier and cleaner to use the `Owner` role anyway.

Comment: you can also take a look at Managed Service Identity, which is a dynamic way to grant resources permissions over Azure

Comment: I actually ended up using a system assigned managed identity. Thanks @4c74356b41.

Comment: This really isn't equivalent.  It allows provisioning of any and all rights whereas PassRole allows the creation of roles with only a subset of the rights of the creator.